# Programatically setting a random image to an ImageButton

Tags: java, android, casting, drawable, imagebutton

I'm trying to have the picture used by my `ImageButton` to be selected randomly.

I think this code should work but there seems to be a problem when passing the resource as a `String`.

```
    ImageButton getClickTime = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clicker);

    Random generator = new Random();
    int generatedRandom = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;
    String randomImage = "R.drawable.bg" + (String.valueOf(generatedRandom)) ;
    Drawable replaceImage = getResources().getDrawable((int) randomImage);

    getClickTime.setImageDrawable((Drawable) replaceImage);
```

I seem to be getting in a bit of a mess with casts of `int`s, `String`s, `drawable`s and `CharSequence`s.

If I manually type in a randomly selected image resource, it works. But if I pass the `String` to a text-box I can see that it's written exactly the same as when I type it in manually.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can not cast string to int --> randomImage. You should get the Bitmap/Drawable from a resource as I described below and set the new image to the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are misunderstanding how Android uses resource ids. The `R` file holds `int` ids that map to resources contained in your app. You are trying to reference a `drawable` resource by casting its `String` reference into an `int`. That is impossible and doesn't make sense.

What I would suggest is that you create an `int[]` that holds the ids of all of your `drawable`s that you want to be randomly selected.

```
    int[] imageIds = { 
            R.drawable.bg1,
            R.drawable.bg2,
            R.drawable.bg3,
            R.drawable.bg4,
            R.drawable.bg5
            // etc for as many images you have
    };
```

Then, randomly select one of those `drawable` ids and set that your to `ImageButton`.

```
    ImageButton getClickTime = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clicker);
    Random generator = new Random();
    int randomImageId = imageIds[generator.nextInt(imageIds.length)];
    getClickTime.setImageResource(randomImageId);
```

Comment: It works! And what a wonderful response. Not only have you given me an example of working code but also an understanding of where my logic is going wrong. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the id of a resource you should use something like this:

```
    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("resource_name", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
     Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use an array of all images and get it by random index:

```
int[] all = {
    R.drawable.bg1,
    R.drawable.bg2,
};
```